# Spring mvc - Css does not work

Tags: css, spring-mvc, configuration, spring-security

I am doing a project with Spring MVC and Spring Security. I have tried many ways to the CSS work, but I did't have any success. In my page.tag there are some examples what I have tried. Also, I tried directly in the html code find out the right URL, but everything does not work.

That is my code.

```
SecurityConfiguration.java

@Override
protected void configure( HttpSecurity http )throws Exception 
{
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers         ( "/resources/**" ).permitAll()
                            .antMatchers         ( "/admin"        ).hasRole( "ADMIN" )
                            .antMatchers         ( "/topics/**"    ).permitAll()
                            .antMatchers         ( "/login"        ).hasRole( "USER"  )
                            .anyRequest          ()
                            .authenticated       ()
                            .and                 ()
                            .formLogin           ()
                            .loginPage           ( "/hello-world" ).permitAll()
                            .and                 ()
                            .logout              ()
                            .logoutRequestMatcher( new AntPathRequestMatcher( "/logout" ) );
}

AppWebConfiguration.java

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers( ResourceHandlerRegistry registry ) 
{
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}


page.tag

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<!--<spring:url value = "/resources/css/main.css"         var = "main" />
<spring:url value = "/resources/css/home_nocache.css" var = "home_nocache" />
<link href="${main}"         rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="${home_nocache}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->

<!--<link href="${homeLess}" rel="stylesheet" /> -->

<link href= "<c:url value='/resources/css/main.css' />"         rel="stylesheet" ></link>
<link href= "<c:url value='/resources/css/home_nocache.css' />" rel="stylesheet" ></link>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
```

What is wrong with my application, does someone can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to permit also css folder in application context xml similar to

if css is  under resources folder

```
<intercept-url pattern="/resources/css/**" access="permitAll()" requires-channel="https" />
```

you have this 
/resources/**

missing 
/css/**

```
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterAfter(new CSRFTokenGeneratorFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers( "/**/" ).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/wizard").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/menu").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/fonts/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/libs/**").permitAll();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated for this and it is the same:

```
@Override
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity http )throws Exception 
    {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers         ( "/resources/**"        ).permitAll()
                                .antMatchers         ( "/resources/css/**"    ).permitAll()
                                .antMatchers         ( "/resources/images/**" ).permitAll()
                                .antMatchers         ( "/admin"               ).hasRole( "ADMIN" )
                                .antMatchers         ( "/topics/**"           ).permitAll()
                                .antMatchers         ( "/login"               ).hasRole( "USER"  )
                                .anyRequest          ()
                                .authenticated       ()
                                .and                 ()
                                .formLogin           ()
                                .loginPage           ( "/hello-world" ).permitAll()
                                .and                 ()
                                .logout              ()
                                .logoutRequestMatcher( new AntPathRequestMatcher( "/logout" ) );
    }
```